# How to pass double value to a textview in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, double

In Android, I am setting the text of a textview to be the answer to a calculation which is a `double` data type.

When the double value has a value of 5, the textview receives the string: `5.0`.

Code:

```
double result = number1/number2;
String finalresult = new Double(result).toString();
textView1.setText(finalresult);
```

How do I format the textView text so that it shows the double value in a consistent format?

Comment: String finalresult=result+""; or String finalresult = Double.toString(result);

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**In Android, assign a double to a textView:**

Use Double.toString:

```
result = number1/number2    
String stringdouble= Double.toString(result);
textview1.setText(stringdouble));
```

or you can use the NumberFormat:

```
Double result = number1/number2;
NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
textview1.setText(nm.format(result));
```

To force for 3 units precision:

```
private static DecimalFormat REAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
textview1.setText(REAL_FORMATTER.format(result));
```

Comment: That does it to 3 decimal places I think. If I wanted to do 0.00001 * 2, it will give me 0

Comment: i think Double.toString should give you the answer in the string if yout result will be 0.0000000000000000001 then also it will give you the same one.

Comment: I still want to format the answer, but not be limited to 3 decimal places

Comment: it will gimme the answer 2.0E-5 of 0.00001*2 as it is in string.

Comment: DO ONE THING OF THE FOLLOWING

private static DecimalFormat REAL_FORMATTER = new DecimalFormat("0.###");

textview1.setText(REAL_FORMATTER2.format(result));

This will definetly print 3 decimal place value

Answer (score 2):

The best way is

```
   String finalresult = String.valueof(result); 
   textview.setText(finalresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the accepted answer and all the other answers provided, since there is a much easier way exists which will also round the value for you, e.g. 4.56 will be shown as 4.6 when you to show 1 digit after decimal point.

e.g., if you want to show only 1 digit after the decimal:

```
double val = 1.8765;
doubleTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", val));
```

If you only want to show rounded integer part

```
double val = 1.8765;
doubleTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.0f", val));
```

You can also set the Locale to Germany, so that 1.08 will be show as 1,08 (as in Germany decimal identifier is comma)

e.g.

```
double val = 1.8765;
doubleTextView.setText(String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%.0f", val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Double num = (double)4+6;
            if(num%2==0) {
                tv.setText(num.intValue()+""); //if you want to remove the decimal place
            } else {
                tv.setText(num+"");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and then you can do your normal code:

```
 result = number1/number2    
 String finalresult = new Double(result).toString();
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
 nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
 nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
 finalresult= nf.format(result);
 textView1.setText(finalresult);
```

and there you can set the maximum or alternatively you can cast to an integer.

```
double number1 =1.0;
double number2 = 10.4;
int result = (int) (number1/number2);
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

the difference between them is that the fist one will round the number to the closest integer and will be a more accurate aproximation, while casting to an integer will lead to have cases where the result beeing 3.9 will be put as 3 and that is a big diference. Therefore I recommend using the `NumberFormat`

Answer (score 0):

```
Double result = number1/number2;//number1 and number2 are double
textView1.setText(""+result);
```

Use the above two lines to set value to textview

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way `text.setText(a+"")`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert the double value to string and set text to textview.

```
String str = String.valueOf(12.123456789);
txtView.setText(str);
```