# setText() of EditText not working inside onTextChanged method

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, textwatcher

From a newbie in android, I have a custom ListView of food items, where each item has item name, quantity and amount. quantity is Edit text and amount is text view. Initially in amount field i'm displaying price for one quantity of item. when the user enters the quantity (Integer) i'm trying to multiply the quantity with amount and display the total amount in the same text view(i.e textView amount)
So i'm using onTextChanged of TextWatcher .

When the user enters the quantity i'm able to receive it and multiply with original amount to get the total amount but when i'm trying to set it using textviewAmount.setText(total amount) inside onTextChanged method its not working.

While searching for the solution I came across this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303469/edittext-settext-not-working-with-fragment/13414452) .which says

> "The EditText appears to have an issue with resetting text in onCreateView"

Below is 
 the sample code of what i have done

Fragment

```
public class FoodListFragment extends Fragment {
List<FoodListCell> foodListCells ;
ListView listView ;
HotelApp hotelApp;
FragmentTransaction ft;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    hotelApp = (HotelApp)getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_listview,container,false);
    Log.d("FoodListActivity" ," onCreate");

    foodListCells = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    foodListCells.add(new FoodListCell("Diet-Vegetable Soup","75.0"));
    foodListCells.add(new FoodListCell("Bean-Bacon ","95.0"));
    foodListCells.add(new FoodListCell("Chicken Noodle Soup","75.0"));

    FoodListAdopter adapter = new FoodListAdopter(hotelApp, R.layout.foodbox_layout, foodListCells);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}}
```

Adopter

```
public class MenuAdopter extends ArrayAdapter<FoodListCell>  {
Context context;
int resource;
List<FoodListCell> foodListCells;
HotelApp hotelApp;
EditText quantity ;
TextView foodBoxAmt ;
Double finalAmt = 0.0, amtForOne = 0.0;

public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    hotelApp = (HotelApp)this.context;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.foodbox_layout,null);

     TextView foodBoxDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodBoxDesc);
              foodBoxAmt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.foodBoxAmt);
      Button  button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addToCartButton);
              quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.qnty);

    final FoodListCell foodListCell = foodListCells.get(position);

    foodBoxDesc.setText(foodListCell.getDesc());
    foodBoxAmt.setText("Rs." +foodListCell.getPrice());
    amtForOne = Double.parseDouble(foodListCell.getPrice().toString());
    quantity.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

             finalAmt=Double.parseDouble(foodListCell.getPrice().toString())*Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            foodBoxAmt.setText("Rs." +finalAmt.toString());
        }}
    );
    return view;

}}
```

TextWatcher

```
public class EditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you get any errors? if yes, provide logcat.

Comment: nope, I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 1):

Well, This is not the right way to handle this, Even if you figure out a way to set the text on textview, After you scroll the page the view is getting destroyed and next time when it gets created it uses the default value and not the one you specified!

I suggest two things, First do not use ListView, Instead use `RecylerView`. RecyclerView is a replacement for ListView since 2 years ago. Second and more importantly whenever your list changes don't update the view, update the model itself, then ask the adapter to recreate the view. It will create the view with updated values. You just have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Please use String.valueOf(value)
If still value does not set than their is some problem in adapter view .

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I'm having problem with foodBoxAmt.setText("Rs." +finalAmt.toString()); which is  Double (amount) , i have edited the question , please go throuth it

Comment: use Double.toString(); like:  foodBoxDesc.setText(Double.toString(foodListCell.getDesc())); also check link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998221/how-to-pass-double-value-to-a-textview-in-android

Comment: String.valueOf(value).